# LESS work around, grid system, box-sizing

Tags: css, grid

unfortunately, I have to develop a site that is supported on IE7.

we know that IE7 does not support box-sizing:border-box; this is making me to specify width for every element separately in IE7 stylesheet.

I want to write some logic in my grid.less, so that the width will be calculated accordingly for ie7..

just like below

```
.grid{
   width:/*width for modern browsers */;
   *width:/*calculate width for ie7 */;
}
```

please help  or point me to any resource.... thank you

Answer (score 0):

LESS does not have a function to allow you to target specific browsers.

The standard method for doing this is with separate style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/grid.css"  />
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie7-grid.css"  />
< ![endif]-->
```

But instead you can use a method like the following [from Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/):

html...

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
```

LESS...

```
.grid{
   width:/*width for modern browsers */;
   .ie7 & {
     width:/*calculate width for ie7 */;
   }
}
```

...which should result in css like...

```
.grid{
  width:/*width for modern browsers */;
}

.ie7 .grid{
  width:/*calculate width for ie7 */;
}
```

Comment: yes, I agree with you Tims, but my idea is to do something like below in less   
.make-column(@columns) {
 
    float: left;
    width: percentage(@columns / @grid-columns);
    padding-left: @grid-column-padding;
    padding-right: @grid-column-padding;
  
  *width: ~"calc(percentage(@columns / @grid-columns) - (2*@{grid-column-padding}))";

  .box-sizing(border-box);
} ... but I am unable to subtract pixels from percentage..